# ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Filter error, bad data

Tags: flutter, dart, http

estoy haciendo una aplicación con Flutter en Android Studio,

la misma lo que hace es un  Request HTTP, dónde quiero recuperar un objeto con listas.

la respuesta json es la siguiente:

```
{
"MQ0401P_FORMREQ_1": [
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300245",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "32000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 400,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "19/06/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300247",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "12000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 150,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "20/06/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300248",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "12000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 150,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "20/06/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300249",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "12000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 150,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "20/06/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300250",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "12000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 150,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "20/06/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300273",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "60000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 1500,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "24/06/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300288",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "120000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 1500,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "03/07/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300289",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "20000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 250,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "06/07/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300307",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "12000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 150,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "11/07/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300311",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00200",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "CATALDO SALVADOR NORBERTO - DE",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "151634",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Acme Fuel Oil",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "32.1",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "16/07/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300313",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00200",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "CATALDO SALVADOR NORBERTO - DE",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "151634",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Acme Fuel Oil",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "32.1",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "16/07/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300314",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00200",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "CATALDO SALVADOR NORBERTO - DE",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "151634",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Acme Fuel Oil",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "32.1",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "16/07/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300315",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00200",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "CATALDO SALVADOR NORBERTO - DE",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "151634",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Acme Fuel Oil",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "32.1",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "16/07/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300317",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00200",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "CATALDO SALVADOR NORBERTO - DE",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "151634",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Acme Fuel Oil",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "530.1",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "16/07/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300319",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00200",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "CATALDO SALVADOR NORBERTO - DE",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "151634",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Acme Fuel Oil",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "160.5",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "16/07/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300320",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "320000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 4000,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "30/07/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300325",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Federico Romero",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4360",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Allen Supplies",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "240000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 3000,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "04/08/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300348",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00200",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "CATALDO SALVADOR NORBERTO - DE",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "151634",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Acme Fuel Oil",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "160.5",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "24/11/2020"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300349",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00001",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Marianella Arrieche",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "64360",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Additives Supplier",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "1000",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "06/05/2021"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300355",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00001",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Gonzalez, Katiana",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "26320",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "06/06/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300361",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00200",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Marianella Arrieche",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "4343",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "Parts Emporium",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "70",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "USD",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "22/07/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300408",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "5883850",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "06/10/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300410",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "5883850",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "06/10/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300411",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Gonzalez, Katiana",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "5980620",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "11/10/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300412",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Gonzalez, Katiana",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "6670620",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "11/10/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300413",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Gonzalez, Katiana",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "6671220",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "11/10/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300416",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Gonzalez, Katiana",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "2389200",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "11/10/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300418",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Gonzalez, Katiana",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "2002121.15",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "11/10/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300419",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Gonzalez, Katiana",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "2002421.38",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "11/10/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300423",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Gonzalez, Katiana",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "2002121.15",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "28/12/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300424",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Gonzalez, Katiana",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "1905651.38",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "28/12/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300426",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "2002121.15",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "28/12/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300427",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00028",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "2750",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "28/12/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300428",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "2002621.15",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "28/12/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300429",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "2195661.15",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "28/12/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300430",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "2003221.15",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "28/12/2022"
    },
    {
        "ORDEN_NRO": "1300432",
        "ORDEN_TIPO": "OP",
        "ORDEN_CIA": "00013",
        "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": "Mario Moreira",
        "PROVEEDOR_COD": "1000",
        "PROVEEDOR_DESC": "FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": "33750",
        "MONEDA_TRAN": "ARS",
        "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": 0,
        "FECHA_ORDEN": "28/12/2022"
    }
]
```

}

hay un body con el username y password que tengo que mandar para la autorizacion
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

uso la librerias siguientes

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
get: ^4.6.5
http: ^0.13.5
shared_preferences: any
flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
```

usé https://app.quicktype.io/ para el parseo y serialización de la respuesta,

me quedó asi:

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final datosProductos = datosProductosFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

DatosProductos datosProductosFromJson(String str) =>         
DatosProductos.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String datosProductosToJson(DatosProductos data) =>         
json.encode(data.toJson());

class DatosProductos {
DatosProductos({
    this.mq0401PFormreq1,
});

List<Mq0401PFormreq1>? mq0401PFormreq1;

factory DatosProductos.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>     
DatosProductos(
    mq0401PFormreq1: json["MQ0401P_FORMREQ_1"] == null ? [] :         
List<Mq0401PFormreq1>.from(json["MQ0401P_FORMREQ_1"]!.map((x) =>     
Mq0401PFormreq1.fromJson(x))),
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "MQ0401P_FORMREQ_1": mq0401PFormreq1 == null ? [] :     
List<dynamic>.from(mq0401PFormreq1!.map((x) => x.toJson())),
};
}

class Mq0401PFormreq1 {
Mq0401PFormreq1({
    this.ordenNro,
    this.ordenTipo,
    this.ordenCia,
    this.iniciadorNombre,
    this.proveedorCod,
    this.proveedorDesc,
    this.costoTotalDom,
    this.monedaTran,
    this.costoTotalFor,
    this.fechaOrden,
});

String? ordenNro;
OrdenTipo? ordenTipo;
String? ordenCia;
IniciadorNombre? iniciadorNombre;
String? proveedorCod;
ProveedorDesc? proveedorDesc;
String? costoTotalDom;
MonedaTran? monedaTran;
int? costoTotalFor;
String? fechaOrden;

factory Mq0401PFormreq1.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>     
Mq0401PFormreq1(
    ordenNro: json["ORDEN_NRO"],
    ordenTipo: ordenTipoValues.map[json["ORDEN_TIPO"]]!,
    ordenCia: json["ORDEN_CIA"],
    iniciadorNombre:     
iniciadorNombreValues.map[json["INICIADOR_NOMBRE"]]!,
    proveedorCod: json["PROVEEDOR_COD"],
    proveedorDesc:     
proveedorDescValues.map[json["PROVEEDOR_DESC"]]!,
    costoTotalDom: json["COSTO_TOTAL_DOM"],
    monedaTran: monedaTranValues.map[json["MONEDA_TRAN"]]!,
    costoTotalFor: json["COSTO_TOTAL_FOR"],
    fechaOrden: json["FECHA_ORDEN"],
);

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "ORDEN_NRO": ordenNro,
    "ORDEN_TIPO": ordenTipoValues.reverse[ordenTipo],
    "ORDEN_CIA": ordenCia,
    "INICIADOR_NOMBRE": 
iniciadorNombreValues.reverse[iniciadorNombre],
    "PROVEEDOR_COD": proveedorCod,
    "PROVEEDOR_DESC": proveedorDescValues.reverse[proveedorDesc],
    "COSTO_TOTAL_DOM": costoTotalDom,
    "MONEDA_TRAN": monedaTranValues.reverse[monedaTran],
    "COSTO_TOTAL_FOR": costoTotalFor,
    "FECHA_ORDEN": fechaOrden,
};
}

enum IniciadorNombre { MARIO_MOREIRA,     
CATALDO_SALVADOR_NORBERTO_DE, FEDERICO_ROMERO,     
MARIANELLA_ARRIECHE, GONZALEZ_KATIANA }

final iniciadorNombreValues = EnumValues({
"CATALDO SALVADOR NORBERTO - DE":     
IniciadorNombre.CATALDO_SALVADOR_NORBERTO_DE,
"Federico Romero": IniciadorNombre.FEDERICO_ROMERO,
"Gonzalez, Katiana": IniciadorNombre.GONZALEZ_KATIANA,
"Marianella Arrieche": IniciadorNombre.MARIANELLA_ARRIECHE,
"Mario Moreira": IniciadorNombre.MARIO_MOREIRA
});

enum MonedaTran { USD, ARS }

final monedaTranValues = EnumValues({
"ARS": MonedaTran.ARS,
"USD": MonedaTran.USD
});

enum OrdenTipo { OP }

final ordenTipoValues = EnumValues({
"OP": OrdenTipo.OP
});

enum ProveedorDesc { PARTS_EMPORIUM, ACME_FUEL_OIL,         
ALLEN_SUPPLIES, ADDITIVES_SUPPLIER, FULFILL_TECHNOLOGY_S_A }

final proveedorDescValues = EnumValues({
"Acme Fuel Oil": ProveedorDesc.ACME_FUEL_OIL,
"Additives Supplier": ProveedorDesc.ADDITIVES_SUPPLIER,
"Allen Supplies": ProveedorDesc.ALLEN_SUPPLIES,
"FULFILL TECHNOLOGY S.A": ProveedorDesc.FULFILL_TECHNOLOGY_S_A,
"Parts Emporium": ProveedorDesc.PARTS_EMPORIUM
});

class EnumValues<T> {
Map<String, T> map;
late Map<T, String> reverseMap;

EnumValues(this.map);

Map<T, String> get reverse {
    reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => MapEntry(v, k));
    return reverseMap;
}
}
```

acá es mi llamada

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;
import"dart:convert";
import"dart:async";
import "package:flutter_oc/Datos_Productos.dart";

class Home extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  List<Datos_Productos> data = <Datos_Productos>[];

  Future<List <Datos_Productos?>> tomar_datos() async{

var url =  "http://quantumconsulting.servehttp.com:925/jderest/v3/orchestrator/MQ0902A_ORCH";
var baseUrl = Uri?.parse(url );
http.Response response  = await  http.post(baseUrl, body:{
  "username": "xx",
  "password": "xx",
}).timeout(Duration(seconds: 90));
var datos = jsonDecode(response.body);

var registros = <Datos_Productos>[];
for(datos in datos ){
  registros.add(Datos_Productos.fromJson(datos));
}
    return registros;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    tomar_datos().then((value){
      setState(() {
    data.addAll(value as Iterable<Datos_Productos>);
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Lista de productos"
        ),
      ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom:  BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1)
                  )
                ),
          child : Text( data[index].mq0401PFormreq1 as String, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
              );
          },
        ),
      )],
        )

    );
  }
}
```

cuándo tiro para ver que me trae, me salta lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he actualizado el IDE, las dependencias, he buscado por internet, pero no he encontrado la solución, si alguien podria decirme o guiarme en mi error, les re agradeceria.